# How can I find all files in Google Drive where a user besides myself is an owner?

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-sharing

I'm an owner on all documents that I create, and whenever I share with someone, I usually give them at most "editor" permissions. So, I'd like to find all documents in which I have given another user "owner" permissions in the past, and review them to see if I want to downgrade them to "editor".

Comment: Please close this thread, it is no longer valid, as you can "Transfer Ownership" in G Suite Admin > Apps > Google Workspace > Settings for Drive and Docs > Transfer ownership. Thanks.

Comment: @magicmaster85 Welcome to [webapps.se]. Only G Suite / Google Workspace admins have access to that option by the other hand the OP didn't mentioned that he was using a G Suite / Google Workspace account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an answer, though you might not like it:

http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2494892

Once you transfer ownership of a file, you lose ownership for yourself. You effectively change the doc from something you own to something that was "shared with you."

There is no way to downgrade a user back to editor unless you contact them to make you the owner again (you can't complete this change once you transfer ownership)

Comment: Just adding on that this effectively means you have no files with you and someone else being the owner at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If this question is regarding a personal Gmail account, then the place you can see where all others are owners of documents that you can "see" is in the "Shared with me" option on the left in Google Drive. That is where you can "see" documents that you are not the owner of, but have editing/view rights.

As of the date of this posting, Google does not have an option for a personal Gmail Accounts to view all files that you've shared with others and provided Editor/Viewer/Commenter rights to.

Reference:
https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9310248?hl=en